# Ajax GET requests to an ASP.NET Page Method?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, post, get

A situation I ran across this week: we have a jQuery Ajax call that goes back to the server to get data

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: fullMethodPath,
    data: data,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        successCallback(response);
    },
    error: errorCallback,
    complete: completeCallback
});
```

`fullMethodPath` is a link to a static method on a page (let's say `/MyPage.aspx/MyMethod`).

```
public partial class MyPage : Page
{
    // snip

    [WebMethod]
    public static AjaxData MyMethod(string param1, int param2)
    {
        // return some data here
    }
}
```

This works, no problem.

A colleague had attempted to replace this call with one where type was "GET". It broke, I had to fix it. Eventually, I went back to POST because we needed the fix quick, but it has been bugging me because semantically a GET is more "correct" in this case.

As I understand it, jQuery translates an object in data to a Query String: `/MyPage.aspx/MyMethod?param1=value1&param2=value2` but all I could get back was the content of the page `MyPage.aspx`.

Is that just a "feature" of Page methods, or is there a way of making a GET request work?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What do you mean with *but all I could get back was the content of the page MyPage.aspx.* ? Didn't the `GET` request work?

Comment: @Felix: He means that he got the full contents of the page instead of calling the page method.

Comment: @Felix: Have clarified what I meant by Page method

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For security reasons, ASP.Net AJAX page methods only support POST requests.

Comment: I assume the security issue is that the method cannot be written to only accept one or the other?

Comment: I mean that because some methods should be limited to POST (because they're updating), it was easier to make it so that all methods are limited to POST, rather than implement a selective limiter like in MVC for ASP.NET.

Comment: @pdr: Actually, I believe the reason is to help prevent CSRF.

Comment: This is one of the reasons I prefer ASP.NET MVC + REST: there's a clear guideline for GET vs POST and no additional technical restrictions imposed on it.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that `ASP.NET` `AJAX` page methods only support `POST` requests for security reasons but you can override this behavior by decorating your `WebMethod` with this these both attribute:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
```

I felt that the accepted answer was incomplete without pointing out a work around.