# How to make JObject and JToken case-insensitive globally

Tags: json.net, json-deserialization

In my new project I see extensive usage of `JToken` and `JObject` like below, where objects are accessed by hardcoded property names.

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(response.Content, this.DefaultSerializerSettings)
           .Value<JToken>("result")
           .Value<JObject>("memberProduct")
           .ToObject<MemberProduct>();
```

The problem here is if property names in the response come with different case, the `.Value<JToken>("result").Value<JObject>("memberProduct")` part fails to pick out the data.

I want to make `JToken` and `JObject` work case-insensitively globally throughout the project, so that I don't have to correct the code all over the place (which I'm planning to do later).

Is there some way to do this?

Comment: Related: [JSON.NET JObject key comparison case-insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12055743/10263)

Comment: @BrianRogers - the fix given there is inline. I wante to fix this globally, like using JsonSerializerSettings, etc

Comment: Yep, I know; that is why I did not mark this question as a duplicate.