# ElasticSearch: Query number field to use like clause as we do for string field

Tags: elasticsearch, search, numbers, field, sql-like

I have 2 fields in my Elasticsearch cache that I created using Oracle river-jdbc.
First column is numeric and second is string as `name`.

I want to use this indexing in autocomplete textbox using jQuery.

All implementation is done for the `name` field.
User can provide any string (at least 3 characters) then hit goes to Elasticsearch with the given string and searches data as it is "In-String" part of `name` field and returns the result.  Similarly to querying in SQL using the `LIKE` operator for `name` field and it's working and data is loaded in the UI.

I want to do the same with the numeric field, but until and unless I give complete value of the numeric field Elasticsearch doesn't return any data. So autocomplete does not works for numeric field.

Below is the code:

Creating river field as:

```
{
    "type": "jdbc",
    "jdbc": {
        "driver": "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver",
        "url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//<ip-addr>:1521/db",
        "user": "user",
        "password": "pwd",
        "sql": "select curr_duns_number as duns, TRIM(name) as company from subject where rownum < 10000"
    },
    "index": {
        "index": "subject",
        "type": "name"
    },
    "properties": {
        "duns": {"type": "string", "store": "yes"},
        "company": {"type": "string"}
    }
}
```

Fetching company field:

```
POST http://<ip-addr>:9200/subject/name/_search
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10,
    "query": {
        "wildcard": {
            "COMPANY": "boo*"
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "COMPANY": {"order": "asc"}
        }
    ]
}
```

After trying various combinations like `wildcard`, `matching`, and `query_string` it doesn't give me results, and I'm left with the following problems:

1. I cannot query numeric fields in a similar way to how it's done using SQL, e.g. `select * from subject where curr_duns_number like  '%123%';`
2. Sorting order is not properly applied as the token for sorting Elasticsearch is considering is usually a word from company name.

Comment: Do you know that this is case sensitive? So, instead of searching for 'COMPANY', you should search for 'company'. Same for sorting by the way. See also [When is case sensitivity important in JSON requests to ASP.NET web services (ASMX)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738321/when-is-case-sensitivity-important-in-json-requests-to-asp-net-web-services-asm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after too much research I could not find any answer on this.  As a solution I changed the type of numeric field into string by appending a string to it and achieve the auto-completion for this project.

For the sake of closing the question I am accepting this answer but if any solution comes in future I will add or any one can add his comments to it.

Thanks