# Solve json capitalization

Tags: asp.net, json

When I access an ASP.NET web api using angular from the same web site, all the first letter lowercase, even if they aren't lowercase on the server.

However, if I move the API's to a different web site and enable CORS, I will receive the JSON exactly as the properties are written on the server.

Is there some way to control this difference? It becomes a mess when I need to move an API to a different web site

Answer (score 0):

The default for serializing output to JSON has changed so you may encounter this issue when migrating .Net frameworks.  You can read more about the issue [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4283) or [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4842) but to resolve you can specify the `DefaultContractResolver`.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Owin `Startup` add this line...

```
 public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var webApiConfiguration = ConfigureWebApi();            
        app.UseWebApi(webApiConfiguration);
    }

    private HttpConfiguration ConfigureWebApi()
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();

        // ADD THIS LINE HERE AND DONE
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(); 

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        return config;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON is case sensitive as a rule JSON keys should have matching case. Some unix servers will ignore case sensitivity but I believe windows servers enforce it.

The error is in the naming conventions in the api or code requesting/processing those keys. Best to use lowercase keys using a under_score as the seperator instead of camelCasing.

http://jsonrpc.org/historical/json-rpc-1-1-alt.html#service-procedure-and-parameter-names

ref: [When is case sensitivity important in JSON requests to ASP.NET web services (ASMX)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738321/when-is-case-sensitivity-important-in-json-requests-to-asp-net-web-services-asm)