# Curl to VB.Net Visual basic

Tags: vb.net, curl, httpwebrequest, 400-bad-request

I am trying to take a Curl example and make it work from within VB.Net using Visual Basic in VS 2022 Community. I have tried everything that I can think of to make this work, but everything returns 400 (Bad Request). My first thoughts concerned the "data" of the request. The target site's example has this:

```
curl --location '/v2/Upload/FilesBase64' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
  "transmitter": {
    "username": "",
    "password": ""
  },
  "simulateUpload": true,
  "files": [
    {
      "fileName": "TEST_dummy1.txt",
      "ContentType": "text/plain",
      "fileContentBase64": "ZHVtbXk="
    }
  ]
}'
```

Which I duplicated with the following code in VB:

```vb
'Get the file content
Dim FileData As String() = {IO.File.ReadAllText(FullFileName)}
Dim byt As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(FileData(0))
Dim Content As String = Convert.ToBase64String(byt)

'Build the body of the request
Dim Dta As New Dictionary(Of Object, Object)
Dim Transmitter As New Dictionary(Of Object, Object) From {
    {"username", USR},
    {"password", PWD}
}

Dta.Add("trasnmitter", Transmitter)
Dta.Add("simulateUpload", True)

Dim FileListarray As New List(Of Object) From {
    New Dictionary(Of Object, Object) From {
        {"filename", "TEST_DataFile.txt"},
        {"ContentType", "text/plain"},
        {"filecontentbase64", Content}
    }
}

Dta.Add("files", FileListarray.ToArray)
Dim Body As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Dta, Formatting.Indented)
Dim BodyBytes As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Body)
```

Which produced the following (formatted here for clarity):

```json
{
    "trasnmitter": {
      "username": "xxxxxxx",
      "password": "xxxxxxx"
    },
    "simulateUpload": true,
    "files": [
      {
        "filename": "TEST_DataFile.txt",
        "ContentType": "text/plain",
        "filecontentbase64": "MUYgICAg=="
      }
    ]
}
```

Lastly, I use this code to sent and retrieve the response:

```vb
Dim BodyBytes As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Body)

'build the web request
Dim URL As String = BaseURL & "/v2/Upload/FilesBase64"
Dim WebRequest As Net.WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(URL)
WebRequest.ContentType = "application/json"
WebRequest.Method = "POST"
WebRequest.ContentLength = Body.Length

'transmit the request
Dim Stream As Stream = WebRequest.GetRequestStream()
Stream.Write(BodyBytes, 0, Body.Length)
Stream.Close()

'get the response
Dim ServerText As String = ""
Try
    Dim Response As WebResponse = WebRequest.GetResponse
    Dim ResponseStream As New StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream)
    ServerText = ResponseStream.ReadToEnd
Catch ex As Exception
    Dim ttt = ""
End Try
```

Please note, this is still highly in development, and I haven't expanded the error handling. If anyone has any ideas on what is wrong, please let me know!

Comment: JSON is [case-sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2738375/11683). Your JSON differs from the sample JSON in the case. Your `ContentLength` is also wrong, should be `BodyBytes.Length`, not `Body.Length`. You are not `Using` any of the streams either.

Comment: Thank you GSerg!  Different error code now, but it's not a bad request!  I will add it to my notes about JSON being case sensitive...  I would have never through that. FK

Comment: @GSerg!; if you place this as the answer, I'll mark it answered and upvote it.  Thank you.

Comment: Also: why load the file into an array with one element, instead of just loading to a string?

Comment: Currently, the app is only supporting a single file, once I get the app to properly communicate, it will be configured to process more than one file at a time.

Comment: There's a typo in the key of `Dta.Add("trasnmitter", Transmitter)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON is [case-sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2738375/11683). Your JSON differs from the sample JSON in its case.

Your `ContentLength` is also wrong, should be `BodyBytes.Length`, not `Body.Length`, in both the assignment of `WebRequest.ContentLength` and the call to `Stream.Write`.

Unrelated to your question, but you should be [`Using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) the request and response streams.