# Calling .Net web service from jQuery+Ajax

Tags: json, web-services, asmx

I'm trying to call a homemade vb.net web service using jQuery+Ajax and I'm struggling with the specifics.

Here's a small function exposed as a web method:

```
<WebMethod()> <ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Xml, UseHttpGet:=True)> _
Public Function GetAllVotes() As XmlDocument

    Dim theVotes = getVotes()
    Dim strResult As String = theVotes.XMLSerialize


    Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
    doc.LoadXml(strResult)
    Return doc

End Function
```

After looking the web I've added the ScriptMethod attributes since i was returning XML but feel free to tell me i don't need them if that's the case.

Then, on the client side, this is the code :

```
function getVotes() {
$.support.cors = true;

$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  contentType: "application/json",
  url: "http://nhrd635:8008/votingmanager.asmx/GetAllVotes",
  data: {},
  dataType: "xml text jsonp",
  success: function(msg) {
      // Hide the fake progress indicator graphic.
      // Insert the returned HTML into the <div>.
      $('#myPlaceHolder').html(msg);
    },
   error: function(msg) {
      $('#myPlaceHolder').html(msg);
        // alert(msg);
   }

});
}
```

I've tried many .. many variations of this code, using post or get, changing the content-type, with or without charset=utf-8. with and without double quotes on data: {}.

i use firebug to trace the output my request. only when i set dataType to jsonp do i ever get a result, but in all instances, the code ends up on the "error" function, even when status give 200 OK. but i know that setting it to jsonp is wrong since that gets my xml treated as actual javascript...

I've read very useful blog entries from a guy on encosia.
(sample: http://encosia.com/3-mistakes-to-avoid-when-using-jquery-with-aspnet-ajax/)

but even following his examples i am unable to get a proper return.

am i doing something wrong that's very obvious? is it the fact that i am returning an xml string rather than a json serialized string?

Answer (score 0):

With more perusing of Stack Overflow and the help of Dave Ward from Encosia, I've managed to solve my problem. I've thought I should post my final solution here, in case that helps someone in the future.

First of all, Web Services were a bad way of doing it, I went with the [HttpHandler solution](http://encosia.com/use-asp-nets-httphandler-to-bridge-the-cross-domain-gap/), as suggested by Dave Ward in reply to my original question.

Returning XML was also a poor choice, that I wasn't really aware of. I added a reference to JSon.net to my project and used it to transform my object into a Json string.

I really wanted to stick to ".net only" to transform into a json string, as suggested in [Dave's blog post](http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/), but somehow I struggled to learn how to instruct .net to automatically transform into Json as in Dave's example, so i took an easy way out with Json.net to "get it working"

Then, in my HttpHandler, I had the response string follow the instructions on this post from StackOverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3703221/1060133

in my case, it was :

```
context.Response.Write(String.Format("{0}({1});", context.Request("callback"), jsonVotes))
```

The jquery call also used the instructions in the above post.

Interesting note, even in a parameter-less call, you have to send empty data like so:

```
$.getJSON('http://url/httpHandler.ashx?callback=?', {}, 
          function(data) {
          alert(data);
          }
);
```

Best of luck...

Comment: Glad you got it working. If you used my HttpHandler solution as-is, the reason you couldn't get JSON out of the service automatically is because the HttpHandler would've been requesting it via `GET` and not adding the `application/json` Content-Type. "ScriptServices" won't return JSON unless those two conditions are met.

Answer (score -1):

I think most of your trouble here probably stems from the cross-origin request (even making a request across different ports on the same machine counts). That's why you were able to get a glimmer of it working when you switched to JSONP. Unfortunately, ASMX "ScriptServices" don't support JSONP, so the data your WebMethod returned wouldn't be a valid parameter to the JSONP callback function that jQuery injects.

The best solution, if at all possible, is to get the service running on the same domain as the page that's calling it. There are various solutions to the cross-origin problem, but none of them are as widely compatible/reliable as a simple XHR request to the same domain that the page making the request resides on.

If you can't do that, consider enabling CORS support for the site serving up votingmanager.asmx. That doesn't work in most versions of IE, but will allow cross-origin requests in other browsers. More info on how to do that here: http://encosia.com/using-cors-to-access-asp-net-services-across-domains/

Tangentially, I'd avoid the extra XML serialization layer if possible. If getVotes() returns something like a List, use that as your return type and let ASP.NET automatically serialize the collection as JSON and then jQuery will automatically convert that to a JavaScript array in your success handler. More info about that here: http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/

Comment: ok, that makes sense, unfortunately this script has to operate cross-domain. in short explanation, I'm attempting to recreate sharepoint 2010 voting capability on our site which has the voting feature disabled by the nice admins ....so we figured we'd create our own by creating a WS that operates with the sharepoint web service.

anyhow ... like i mentionned, when using the jsonp datatype, firebug sees a response. even if it falls in the "error" handler, is it possible to read the response from jquery in the error handler then somehow hack my way to re-cast it / re-convert it back to html?

Comment: @Stephane: If you don't control the remote server, another option is to use an HttpHandler on the local server to act as a relay that doesn't violate the same-origin policy: http://encosia.com/use-asp-nets-httphandler-to-bridge-the-cross-domain-gap/

Comment: again, interesting, it seems you blogged on just about every issue I'm hitting lately... After realizing the impossibility to get the ajax response even in jsonp form, I decided that my simplest option was to "convert" my web service into a series of small web pages which i could call with a simple get request, but that is ugly and cumbersome. I don't understand everything about your HttpHandler post yet but it seems promising. Thanks a lot for your help, its really appreciated.