# ScriptMethod problems with Mono and FastCGI/Nginx

Tags: asp.net, mono, nginx, fastcgi

I'm porting a .Net application to Mono running via FastCGI on Nginx and generally everything is going swell.

ScriptMethods/WebMethods are not working however -- they throw a 500:

```
System.Web.HttpException: Method POST is not allowed when accessing file /site/path/widget/editwidgets.aspx/SaveLayout
```

Switching to `[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true)]` doesn't help and just leads to other problems.

What am I missing here? I've seen what I think is a solution for lighttpd (mapping all .Net extensions to .aspx -- though I'm not sure why that would work -- it certainly appears that Mono is handling the request).

Comment: Have you tried [this][1]?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613374/using-asmx-using-lighttpd-and-mono-fastcgi/8131138

Answer (score 0):

I'm porting several app's also and ScriptMethod/PageMethod is a pain. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948628/asp-net-passing-json-from-jquery-to-ashx) shows a solution that I use.