# Deserialize JSON string to c# object

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

My Application is in Asp.Net MVC3 coded in C#.
This is what my requirement is. I want an object which is in the following format.This object should be achieved when I deserialize the Json string.

```
var obj1 = new { arg1=1,arg2=2 };
```

[image]

After using the below code:

```
string str = "{\"Arg1\":\"Arg1Value\",\"Arg2\":\"Arg2Value\"}";
JavaScriptSerializer serializer1 = new JavaScriptSerializer();
object obje = serializer1.Deserialize<object>(str);
```

The object what i get i.e **obje** does not acts as obj1

[image]

Here, in this example my JSON string is static, but actually JSON string is going to be dynamically generated runtime, so i won't be able get Arg1 and Arg2 all the time.

Comment: This question exists already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object

Comment: @jbtule thanks, i tried the code given at the above link. After some edit, it gave me a similar object but I am still not able to use it as i can use obj1 in my code

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think the JavaScriptSerializer does not create a dynamic object.

So you should define the class first:

```
class MyObj {
    public int arg1 {get;set;}
    public int arg2 {get;set;}
}
```

And deserialize that instead of `object`:

```
serializer.Deserialize<MyObj>(str);
```

Not testet, please try.

Answer (score 16):

Use this code:

```
var result=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<yourObj>>(jsonString);
```

Comment: 100% Right Answer. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

I believe you are looking for this:

```
string str = "{\"Arg1\":\"Arg1Value\",\"Arg2\":\"Arg2Value\"}";
JavaScriptSerializer serializer1 = new JavaScriptSerializer();
object obje = serializer1.Deserialize(str, obj1.GetType());
```

Answer (score 4):

This may be useful:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
dynamic jsonObject = serializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(json);
```

Where "json" is the string that contains the JSON values.  Then to retrieve the values from the jsonObject you may use

```
myProperty = Convert.MyPropertyType(jsonObject["myProperty"]);
```

Changing MyPropertyType to the proper type (ToInt32, ToString, ToBoolean, etc).

Answer (score 4):

solution :

```
 public Response Get(string jsonData) {
     var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<modelname>(jsonData);
     var data = StoredProcedure.procedureName(json.Parameter, json.Parameter, json.Parameter, json.Parameter);
     return data;
 }
```

model:

```
 public class modelname {
     public long parameter{ get; set; }
     public int parameter{ get; set; }
     public int parameter{ get; set; }
     public string parameter{ get; set; }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Same problem happened to me. So if the service returns the response as a JSON string you have to deserialize the string first, then you will be able to deserialize the object type from it properly:

```
string json= string.Empty;
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), true))
        {
            json= new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<string>(streamReader.ReadToEnd());

        }
//To deserialize to your object type...
MyType myType;
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
         {
            byte[] jsonBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@json);
            memoryStream.Write(jsonBytes, 0, jsonBytes.Length);
            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using (var jsonReader = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8,          XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max, null))
            {
                var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(MyType));
                myType = (MyType)serializer.ReadObject(jsonReader);

            }
        }
```

4 Sure it will work.... ;)