# How to get json output from a webservice as a datatable in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

i have a webservice (wsdl) generated from a java project. its output is getting as json format.
something like this
    `[{"pid":163686,"chartno":null,"lName":"Bec&&kwith","fName":"Burt","mName":null,"line1":"312 HILL ROAD","line2":null,"city":"Hillsboro","state":"Missouri","pinCode":null,"phone":"123456879","dob":"1947-01-01","gender":"Male","ssn":null,"martialStatus":null,"guarantor":null,"sig":null,"priInsname":null,"priPolNo":null,"secInsname":null,"secPolNo":null}]`

i want to use this data in my c# web application to display it in a grid.. how can i get this data into a datatable?
how to format the json output to a table structure if multiple data comes?

The heading will be pid, chartno, ... etc .

i dont want to make it too complex... i just want the json output to store into a dictnory or somthing ..
thank u

Comment: Parse your JSON use [this](http://json.codeplex.com/)

Comment: is there any way to deserialize json without using any external component. i am using visual studio 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would deserialize the JSON in to a custom c# object instead of a DataTable.

[Deserialize JSON string to c# object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10350982/deserialize-json-string-to-c-sharp-object)

Essentially you can use the JavaScript serializer to deserialize your JSON string into the object. I recommend this over the data table since you would have to manually map it to the table The grid should be able to consume a List of your custom object instead of a data table

Comment: Indeed. A DataTable is a bloated object made for other purposes. Ultimately all you need of it here is its quasi-collection properites.

Comment: yes. i only need the data from json to map to any of the collections in c#. how can i do it with in the boundary of .net framework 3.5 without using any of the external dlls

Answer (score 1):

You need to Parse json , you can JQuery to parse json object.