# how to deserialize array in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have an array object which looks like items = ['a','b','c'] which is stored in 'HiddenField1' id.
How would i deserialize it in code behind?

```
funciton getItems(){
   var items = [];
   $("HiddenField1").val(JSON.stringify(items));
}
```

code-behind (page_load)

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "items", "<script type='text/javascript'>getItems();</script>", false);
string[] items = ??
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this **[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10350982/deserialize-json-string-to-c-sharp-object)** can help you!

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer1 = new JavaScriptSerializer();
serializer.Deserialize<YOUROBJECT>(str);
```

Comment: [Review] Not a bad first post Thales! One thing Stack Overflow recommends however that your answer lacks is adding a **summary** when posting a link. Welcome to Stack Overflow, recommended reading [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Get Newtonsoft JSON from the nuget repo http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<String[]>(items);
```