# Passing JSON data to a webservice

Tags: asp.net, json

I have two parameters (categoryName and categoryDescription) that I need to pass to the web service using JSON. I found the syntax to pass categoryName but have not been able to get the correct syntax to pass both parameters. Here is the code.

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#hbtnCreateCategory').click(function(event) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "lwsServiceData.asmx/CreateHelpDeskCategory",
                data: "{'categoryName': '" + $('#categoryName').val() + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(msg) {
                    AjaxSucceeded(msg);
                },
                error: AjaxFailed
            });

        });

        function AjaxSucceeded(result) {
            alert(result.d);
            $('#result').val = result.d;
        }

        function AjaxFailed(result) {
            alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
        }

    });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

data: "{ categoryName  :'" + $('#categoryName').val() + "' , categoryDescription: '" + $('#categoryDescription').val() + "' }",

Don't forget to update CreateHelpDeskCategory to accept both arguments.

To add a third argument, use the following:

data: "{ categoryName:'" + + $('#categoryName').val() + "' , categoryDescription: '" + + $('#categoryDescription').val() + "', modifiedBy:'jsmith' }",

Comment: Alison,
Your code worked after I replaced the ++ with +. I want to pass a third string parameter to the web server called "modifiedBy". I used the following code but get an error:
data: "{ categoryName :'" + $('#categoryName').val() + "' , categoryDescription: '" + $('#categoryDescription').val() + "' , modifiedBy:'jsmith ' " + "' }",
Thanks in advanced.
NC8

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
data: {categoryName: JSON.stringify($('#categoryName').val()),
       categoryDescription: JSON.stringify($('#categoryDescription').val())}
```

as a parameter of `$.ajax` method. The function `JSON.stringify` can used to serialize any data to JSON (can be downloaded from http://www.json.org/js.html). Manual serialization is not good at least because the possibility that the string which should be serialized contain characters which must be escaped (like '"' or '\' see http://www.json.org/).

Look at also to the another question which I answered before: [How do I build a JSON object to send to an AJAX WebService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737525/how-do-i-build-a-json-object-to-send-to-an-ajax-webservice/2738086#2738086)

Comment: Oleg,
I find your code to be very readable and easy to understand. However, I pasted it onto my code and it did not work.

What am I missing?
Thanks,
NC8

Comment: WS code:
[WebMethod]
public int CreateHelpDeskCategory(string categoryName, string categoryDescription){DataCenterDataContext db = new DataCenterDataContext();
        try{
            HelpDeskCategory cat = new HelpDeskCategory {
                CategoryName = categoryName.Trim(),
                CategoryDescription = categoryDescription.Trim(),
                CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
            };
            db.HelpDeskCategories.InsertOnSubmit(cat);
            db.SubmitChanges();
            return 1;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return 0;
        }

Comment: I don't see in your code `[ScriptMethod (ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]` attribute. Do you use it or set the same behavior in web.config (it is possible in .NET 4.0)?

Answer (score 0):

```
data: "{'categoryName': '" + $('#categoryName').val() + "', 'categoryDescription': 'some description'}"
```

and if it needs to be dynamic:

```
data: "{'categoryName': '" + $('#categoryName').val() + "', 'categoryDescription': '" + $('#categoryDescription').val() + "'}"
```

Comment: I need to get the categoryDescription from 
<input id="categoryDescription" type="text" /><br />
so I think I need to use something like 
$('#categoryDescription').val()

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I suggested.

Comment: Darin:
Your code works!! I am coming from ASP.Net and this is my first time learning JSON. I still have a bit of a problem concatenating the strings. Based on your samples I put together the following data and it does not work. Could you please check it out and let me know where I am making the mistake?

   data: "{'categoryName': '" + $('#categoryName').val() + "', 'createdBy': 'jsmith' " + "', 'categoryDescription': '" + $('#categoryDescription').val() + "'}",

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There's also this: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/