# How to get jquery/ajax parameters on the server

Tags: jquery

This is my code:

```
$.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx",
            data: "category=2&city=Boston",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            processData :false,
            error: function (json) {
                alert(json.statusText);
            },
            success: function (json) {
                alert(json.statusText);

            }
        });
```

How can I get my parameters (`category=2&city=Boston`) to the server?
Request parameters is always `null`.

Answer (score 4):

You don't write anything about the server, but you use both `contentType` and `dataType` contains JSON. So probably you want to send JSON data to the server and receive also JSON data back. The data from the string "category=2&city=Boston" are not in JSON format.

You should replace the string "category=2&city=Boston" to 'category=2&city="Boston"'. I recommend you to read my old answer [How do I build a JSON object to send to an AJAX WebService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737525/how-do-i-build-a-json-object-to-send-to-an-ajax-webservice/2738086#2738086) and use `JSON.stringify` function (a part of json2.js which can be downloaded from http://www.json.org/js.html)

So your code should be better modified to the following

```
var myCategory = 2;
var myCity = "Boston";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Default.aspx",  // probably it should by a ASMX amd not ASPX page?
    data: { category: myCategory, city: JSON.stringify(myCity) },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    error: function (json) {
        alert(json.statusText);
    },
    success: function (json) {
        // you should probably modify next line because json can be an object
        alert(json.statusText);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works for me calling a servlet in JAVA, not sure about .NET but it's worth a try.

```
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "/Default.aspx?category=2&city=Boston"
     //more config stuff here
});
```