# Sending parameters in AJAX call

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, jquery

This has been asked before by others, but I have not been able to use their answers.

I am trying to sending some data by doing the following:

```
 function addForumPost() {
            var title = jQuery('#forumTitle').val();
            var message = htmlEncode(jQuery('#message').htmlarea("toHtmlString"));
            var tagNames = addTags();

            var dataPost = $.toJSON({ title: 'testingsadf', message: message, tagNames: tagNames });
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Create",
            data: dataPost,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
            }
        });
    }
```

I have checked, and doubled checked that the input contains data, but I only receive the data from the message parameter in my controller. The other two values are null. As you can see in the the example above, I have even assigned some static text to the title parameter, but I still only receive data for the message parameter.

The controller looks like this:

```
  [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Create(string title, string message, List<string> tagNames)
        {
          ....
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is very simple. If you have an action which returns `JsonResult` then it means **not** that you have to send also JSON encoded input parameters to the method. Just remove the usage of `$.toJSON()` and use the object as a value of `data` parameter of `jQuery.ajax` (see the answer of Darin for example).

If you call ASMX Web Service instead of ASP.NET MVC action you **have to** use `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` and convert the values of all web-method parameters to JSON but in a little other way (see  [How do I build a JSON object to send to an AJAX WebService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737525/how-do-i-build-a-json-object-to-send-to-an-ajax-webservice/2738086#2738086)). But ASP.NET MVC hat no such requirement. MVC converts the input parameters which you send with respect of `Parse` method (`int.Parse`, `DateTime.Parse` and so on) and not deserialize from JSON. So if you search for code examples look exactly which technology are used on the backend: ASP.NET MVC, ASMX web serveces or WFC.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the [`traditional`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) parameter starting from jQuery 1.4. This works for me:

```
var title = 'title';
var message = 'message';
var tagNames = ['tag1', 'tag2'];

jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Home/Create',
    data: { title: title, message: message, tagNames: tagNames },
    dataType: 'json',
    traditional: true,
    success: function (result) {
    }
});
```

With this action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(
    string title, 
    string message, 
    IEnumerable<string> tagNames
)
{
    return Json(new
    {
        Title = title,
        Message = message,
        TagNames = tagNames
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't have to post json for the type of action you described.
2. You don't have to manually assemble the fields into a map. Use .serializeArray()

   var postData = $('.myform').serializeArray()