# How to call a cross domain WCF Service from JQuery Ajax with Parameters

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf, cross-domain

I have one Cross Domain WCF. I have already implemented the CORS on the service.

If the method don't have any parameter, then I can call it using JQuery Ajax.

But the problem is, when the method is having any parameter then some error is occurred after the JQuery Ajax call.

```
  $.support.cors = true;
  $.ajax({
    url: servicePath,
    crossDomain: true,
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    data: '{"name": "xyz"}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: true,
    success: function (response) {
      alert('s');
    },
    error: function (error) {
      alert(error.status + ' : ' + error.statusText);
    }
  })
```

[Server Side Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1N0u.png)

Comment: is your service a webapi? can you pass the parameters in url,m lik yourservce.svc/parameter1/parameter2 ?

Comment: it is not webapi. it is wcf application. the method type is 'post'.

Comment: since you can reach your endpoint without parameters, maybe this link can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876784/calling-wcf-service-with-jquery-and-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Coulde you provide the complete error message? And what is your wcf web.config fiel.
I guess you can add this attribute with your service file.
Like below:`[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode =

            AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class Service1
    {
        [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public Customer GetCustomer()
        {
            return new Customer() { Name = "Pranay", Address = "1 Ahmedabad" };
        }
    }`