# Web service method is not accessible from jQuery ajax

Tags: web-services, jquery

I am using jQuery ajax to calling a web service method but is is not doing and generating error..

The code is here for jQuery ajax in asp page

```
var indexNo = 13; //pass the value

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#a1").click(function() {
         $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "myWebService.asmx/GetNewDownline",
                data: "{'indexNo':user_id}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(msg) {
                $("#divResult").text(msg.d);
                }
        });
    });
    });
```

and this is the is web service method

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using TC.MLM.DAL;
using TC.MLM.BLL.AS;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for myWebService
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 

[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

public class myWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public myWebService()
    {
        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string GetNewDownline(string indexNo)
    {
        IndexDetails indexDtls = new IndexDetails();
        indexDtls.IndexNo = "13";
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = TC.MLM.BLL.AS.Index.getIndexDownLineByIndex(indexDtls);
        indexNoDownline[] newDownline = new indexNoDownline[ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count];

        for (int count = 0; count <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; count++)
        {
            newDownline[count] = new indexNoDownline();
            newDownline[count].adjustedid = ds.Tables[0].Rows[count]["AdjustedID"].ToString();
            newDownline[count].name = ds.Tables[0].Rows[count]["name"].ToString();
            newDownline[count].structPostion = ds.Tables[0].Rows[count]["Struct_Position"].ToString();
            newDownline[count].indexNo = ds.Tables[0].Rows[count]["IndexNo"].ToString();
            newDownline[count].promoterId = ds.Tables[0].Rows[count]["PromotorID"].ToString();
            newDownline[count].formNo = ds.Tables[0].Rows[count]["FormNo"].ToString();
        }

        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string resultedDownLine = js.Serialize(newDownline);

        return resultedDownLine;
    }

    public class indexNoDownline
    {
        public string adjustedid;
        public string name;
        public string indexNo;
        public string structPostion;
        public string promoterId;
        public string formNo;
    }
}
```

Please help me something.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your input JSON data. Instead of manual serialization you should try to use the builtin JSON class. Ex.

```
$.ajax({
   ...
   data: JSON.stringify({ indexNo: user_id }),
   ...
 });
```

This should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the art how you implement serialization in the server. Just add ScriptMethod attribute with `ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json`. Using of HTTP GET is also possible with respect of additional (optional) attribute `UseHttpGet = true`

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod (UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string GetNewDownline(string indexNo)
```

The database access can be also improved if you will use `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` classes or another versions of `DbDataReader` depends of you database source (`OleDbDataReader`, `OracleDataReader`, `OdbcDataReader`, `DataTableReader`). If you prefer work with strong typed data, then `SqlDataAdapter` generated by Visual Studio will be better version of `DataSet`. To do this just add a new Item to your profject, choose "Data" / "DataSet" and then add a Query or `TableAdapter`.

If you decide to use `HTTP` `GET` you should don't make corresponding modification of your `web.config` file.

```
<configuration>
  <!-- ... -->
  <system.web>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
    <!-- ... -->
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

About usage of `JSON.stringify` I have the same opinion like "egyedg".

I recommend you to look following links:

[Can I return JSON from an .asmx Web Service if the ContentType is not JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670147/can-i-return-json-from-an-asmx-web-service-if-the-contenttype-is-not-json/2671583#2671583)

[How do I build a JSON object to send to an AJAX WebService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737525/how-do-i-build-a-json-object-to-send-to-an-ajax-webservice/2738086#2738086)

[JQuery ajax call to httpget webmethod (c#) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651091/jquery-ajax-call-to-httpget-webmethod-c-not-working/2656543#2656543)