# How to build a WCF to ASP.net MVC (client) architecture using JSON format/endpoint as way of communication?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, json, web-services

I am leaning towards WCF as my main source of service (I may need multiple end-points in the future), and here are the things that I have been stuck at...

- **WCF to CLIENT:** How can I make my MVC accept JSON data from WCF service and parse it into C# primitive/complex types?
- **CLIENT to WCF:** How can I send JSON formatted data from MVC to WCF and have it parsed to C# primitive/complex types?
- *side question: How can I make WCF use REST as its protocol and transmit JSON format data? Do I use REST starter kit or is it built in on WCF?*

Basically, this is my architecture:

**WCF** === *(format: JSON)* ===> **ASP.net MVC 3** (...and back)

**WCF** === *(format: JSON)* ===> **misc client** (...and back)

code samples would help greatly!

Thanks in advance for the help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF RESTful web services are going to be your friend. In order to force the web service to return JSON take a look at [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3027880/635634).

Update: If you have control over both the client and the service it may be worth looking into WCF Data Services as an alternative. Less code = more productivity (in some cases ;))

Comment: i heard that Data Services doesn't support many LINQ features.. how is it in your experience?

Comment: Data Services is strongly tied to Linq to Entities. What linq features are you concerned about being left out?

Comment: Server side paging can be implemented using: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2010/02/02/server-paging-in-data-services.aspx, or on the client side: http://solidcoding.blogspot.com/2007/11/paging-with-linq.html. While I haven't used the standard LINQ paging approach in the past against Data Services I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: @JanCarloViray - On second thought, you're talking about consuming a WCF Data Service from an MVC page (presumably using AJAX), so if you are looking for an OData client library for Javascript, take a look at http://www.odata.org/developers/odata-sdk. It talks about OData clients for various languages including Javascript. In that case I would probably suggest utilizing server side paging because you don't really have Linq in Javascript to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

A RESTful WCF service will work, like M.Babcock said, but you can just use Ajax to call your controller action; you call your controller, which in turn calls your WCF service and returns a JsonResult. Something like this...

Controller:

```
public JsonResult GetData() 
{
    var result = wcf.GetSomeData();
    return Json(result); 
}
```

View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#mybutton').click(function() {
             $.getJSON("/Home/GetData", null, function(data) {
                 alert(data);
             });
          });
    });
</script>
```

Here's a [link](http://shashankshetty.wordpress.com/2009/03/04/using-jsonresult-with-jquery-in-aspnet-mvc/) to a better tutorial.

Comment: hmm.. seems like asp.net MVC as a 'REST service' would be better solution for this one huh.