# Send JSON as response from a WebService in .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, json, web-services

I'm building a Web Service in VB.NET and I want to answer using JSON.
Currently my answers looks like this

```
{\"myVar1\" : \"From moscow\", \"myVar2\" : \"With love\"}
```

I would like to be able to use " (and CarriageReturn), and have the reponse like this :

```
{"myVar1" : "From moscow", "myVar2" : "With love"}
```

How can I avoid this transcoding of the " in \" ?

Here is my interface definition :

```
<OperationContract()>
<WebGet(UriTemplate:="/TemplateGet?ID={id}",
        ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, 
        BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)>
Function TemplateGet(id As String) As String
```

My answer is plain String :

```
Function TemplateGet(id As String) As String Implements ISearch.TemplateGet
    Dim reponse As String = "{""MyVar1"" : ""From moscow"", ""MyVar2"" : ""With love""}"
    Return reponse
End Function
```

Comment: I used "ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json" and it works fine (without the \"). are you sure it is not only on the debugger view?

Comment: Hmm. you could be right... I've to check this.

Comment: No, it doesn't seems so. I created a small WS Client and I get that String with \" from the service...

Comment: did you check the response in a browser???

Comment: Yes! I also use RESTClient extension in Firefox... In fact as I look at the raw data sent, there are [ ... ] around it.

Comment: I added the code of my fonction, just in case...

Comment: Nice discussion found here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026934/how-can-i-return-json-from-my-wcf-rest-service-net-4-using-json-net-without

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a VB.net guy, (and i didn't find a vb example) so the link will use c# - but with a simple translation to vb it should be the same.

When you write a wcf service, you shouldn't write the serialization (to json in your case) by yourself.

you can return an object (which you should register as a known type - see the example below) and the result will be serialized for you.

example for a wcf service with objects: http://www.freddes.se/2010/05/19/wcf-knowntype-attribute-example/

in your case you should create a class like that:

```
   [DataContract]
   public class MyServiceResultClass
   {
       [DataMember]
       public string myVar1 {get; set;}

       [DataMember]
       public string myVar2 {get; set;}
   }
```

register `MyServiceResultClass` as a service known type, and change your method to something like that:

```
   Function TemplateGet(id As String) As String Implements ISearch.TemplateGet
      Dim reponse As MyServiceResultClass = new MyServiceResultClass() // -- Change to vb syntax here
      Return reponse
   End Function
```

and thats it... you will get the response in json