# Why I can't use Newtonsoft.Json JsonConvert.SerializeObject in wcf service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I am using Newtonsoft.Json dll for Serialize object to return string from wcf service. When I call other simple method from service it works fine but when I call method which serialize object into string and return that string its not working. Below is my code of service.

```
public string GetString()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }

    public string GetData(int i)
    {
        My_Entities ME = new MY_Entities();

        ApplicationVM oVM = new ApplicationVM()
        {
            AP_M_BloodGroup = ME.AP_M_BloodGroup.ToList().ElementAtOrDefault(i),
            AP_M_DayMaster = ME.AP_M_DayMaster.ToList().ElementAtOrDefault(i)
        };
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oVM, Formatting.Indented);
    }
```

Both method work for local but after hosting when calling `GetData()` method it will give error message `"Access Denied"` at client side.
So, what is the problem and what I need to put extra?

When I put client side code in try-catch block it gives message like:

> Message: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed

Comment: what is your class `ApplicationVM` doing? is it accessing some resources? what identity is you application pool running under?

Comment: ApplicationVM is simple Entity model class which consume two entity class for BloodGroup and DayMaster.

Comment: Are you able to create context class within `GetData` method? What credentials are you using to connect to your database? first method simply returns an constant - that has nothing to say.

Comment: yes, it works proper and also work fine with inbuilt js serialization.

Comment: Will this help? under system.web <trust level="Full" /> in web.config

Comment: BTW, where is WCF service hosted? IIS?

Comment: In IIS working fine but after hosting on web server this problem started.

Comment: Than it might be a problem with trust level. Here is a problem looking like yours [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e415255c-0fd3-4500-8e46-4d36220913fe/systemsecuritysecurityexception-request-for-the-permission-of-type?forum=wcf)

Comment: Thanks @d_z it will work. I miss that in my web.config file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I return json from my WCF rest service (.NET 4), using Json.Net, without it being a string, wrapped in quotes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026934/how-can-i-return-json-from-my-wcf-rest-service-net-4-using-json-net-without)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use

```
<trust level="Full" />
```

under system.web  in web.config as per @d_Z suggested and it works.