# Spring-portlet POST ajax xmlHttpRequest

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc, xmlhttprequest, portlet

Could please anybody who has experiences with processing post xmlHttpRequests with Spring DispatcherPortlet, tell me what is the best way to do it ? I'm using YUI io module and Jackson Object Mapper as an example :

```
@ResourceMapping(value="stuff")
public void method(ResourceResponse response){
   Person person = new Person();
   person.setWeight(150);
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   try{
      mapper.writeValue(response.getWriter(), person);
      }
   ...
  }
```

Ajax:

```
function() {

   var A = AUI();

   A.io("<portlet:resourceURL id="stuff" />", {
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        description: 'value'
      }
   });
     }
```

[**This**](https://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-7344) is the issue where you can vote up that spring-portlet environment will have the same support that common spring-mvc has. Which is @ResponseBody, data conversion to JSON etc. Now AFAIK one has to do it manually...

EDITED: Figured out the solution

PLEASE: Take a look at this issue which is better formulated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782971/handling-ajax-requests-with-spring-portlet

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782971/handling-ajax-requests-with-spring-portlet doesn't appear to exist any longer

Answer (score 0):

How do you construct the URL? I think you're creating a Action URL, perhaps it should be an render URL. It means, instead of `<portlet:actionURL/>` you should be using `<portlet:renderURL/>`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It must be <portlet:resourceURL id="sample" /> which is part of jsr 283 spec. and it was created mainly for ajax requesting. And the correct annotation is @ResourceMapping(value="sample") ... But spring Portlet is not good for handling ajax request, there is no built-in support for JSON responding, one has to do it manually... There is this issue, please vote up if you like portlets and spring : https://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-7344

Comment: Thanks @lisak, I will definitively vote up for this nice-to-have feature.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the best way to respond to ajax requests in spring portlets is described in this blog post [Marshal Json data using Jackson in Spring MVC with Jaxb Annotations](http://hillert.blogspot.com/2011/01/marshal-json-data-using-jackson-in.html)

This also helpful [Create JSON response for AJAX request in spring 3.0](http://rwehner.wordpress.com/2010/06/09/2-ways-to-create-json-response-for-ajax-request-in-spring3/)

Unfortunately it is not so fancy as it would be in spring-web-mvc