# Call WebService method by jQuery

Tags: jquery, web-services

I'm trying to call a WebService method by jQuery, but it's not working.

The code is given below...

jQuery

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: "{}",
    dataType: "json",
    url:'test.asmx/GetSurvey',
    contentType:"application/json;charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data) {
        $("#Span1").html(data.d);
    }
});
```

test.asmx (WebService) code given below:

```
[WebMethod]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string GetSurvey()
{
    return "Question: Who is Snoopy?";
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Use from console.log(data) in success function to check your service response.its help you

Comment: how can i add  console.log(data)

Answer (score 1):

here jquery code :

```
$.ajax({
type : "POST",
data : "",
dataType : "json",
url : 'test.asmx/GetSurvey',
contentType : "application/json;charset=utf-8",
success : function(data) {
    $("#Span1").html(data);
 }
});
```

You have copy pasted the code from some where and didnt remove '**`enter your code`**' in url
so that was the problem..

**EDITED:**

```
url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/test.asmx/GetSurvey") %>',
```

try to pass the path in such way

Comment: Request URL:http://localhost:6276/ExaminationSystem/test.asmx/GetSurvey
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error

Comment: it means the path is not correct, please check your path "test.asxm/GetSurvey" is it the exactly path ?

Comment: yes it is.....as the test.asmx is on the root of my project....named examinationsystem i added it on root..and passed the url    url: '../test.asmx/GetSurvey',

Comment: url:  '../test.asmx/GetSurvey',

Comment: in cs i can easily call methods...but i want to call it from from webservice.....so i try this simple example but its not wotking.....

Answer (score 1):

in your ajax call

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
data: "{}",
dataType: "json",
url:'test.asmx/GetSurvey',
contentType:"application/json;charset=utf-8",
success: function(data) {
console.log(data);
    $("#Span1").html(data.d);
}
});
```

you can see this log with Chrome devtools in Console Tab.
In addition you can monitor your request/response  with Chrome devtools in Network Tab

Check it for more information about Chrome devtools [Chrome Dev Tools: Networking and the Console](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/chrome-dev-tools-networking-and-the-console/)

Comment: @user2322540 your ajax request can call get survey?

Comment: @user2322540 che this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/287430/Calling-ASP-Net-WebMethods-using-jQuery

Answer (score -1):

1) `"Question: Who is Snoopy?"` is not JSON.

2) `data.d` references nothing.

3) `enter code here` is jibberish, remove it.

4) If you don't have data to send then you can leave out `data` in your AJAX options, `"{}"` is the wrong way to define your parameters anyway.

Have a read of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196569/returning-json-from-asmx-and-handling-it-correctly-in-javascript) to get a good idea of how to send/return JSON and use it correctly.

Comment: 1) my code is returning string..so json is correct...i used it earlier too...2)data.d will return the 'Question: Who is Snoopy?' 3)'enter code here' is for user to understand its not wriiten by me...when i post this question its automatically write that