# asmx web service, json, javascript/jquery?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, json, asmx

I am using asmx to retrieve some data from DB,

```
public class TestPage1
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
}




    [WebMethod]
    public EntityLayer.TestPage1 GetData(int id)
    {
        TestPage1 test = TestPage1.GetData(id).SingleOrDefault();
        return test;
    }


$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  url: "WebService.asmx/GetData",
  data: "{id}",
  dataType: "json"
});
```

How Do I desrialize test object in javascript??
 and is there a better way?
thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I recommend you look my previous answer for the close questions [How do I build a JSON object to send to an AJAX WebService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737525/how-do-i-build-a-json-object-to-send-to-an-ajax-webservice/2738086#2738086) and [Can I return JSON from an .asmx Web Service if the ContentType is not JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670147/can-i-return-json-from-an-asmx-web-service-if-the-contenttype-is-not-json/2671583#2671583)

The correct code should looks like following

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod (ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public EntityLayer.TestPage1 GetData(int id)
{
    TestPage1 test = TestPage1.GetData(id).SingleOrDefault();
    return test;
}
```

and

```
var myData = 5;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "WebService.asmx/GetData",
    //data: {id:JSON.stringify(myData)},
    data: JSON.stringify({id:myData}),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response){
        alert("UserName=" + response.d.UserName +
              ", FirstName=" + response.d.FirstName +
              ", MiddleName=" + response.d.MiddleName+
              ", LastName=" + response.d.LastName);
    }
})
```

where `JSON.stringify` is a function from the script json2.js which you can download from http://www.json.org/js.html.

If the `id` values are integer `JSON.stringify(myData)` are the same as `myData`, but for all more complex examples I strictly recommend you to use this function.

How you can also see from the code the all results of the web method will be saved in the property `d`, so you should use for example `response.d.FirstName` syntax to access the first name.

**UPDATED**: In case of HTTP GET the `data` parameter should be `{id:JSON.stringify(myData)}`. In case of HTTP POST: `JSON.stringify({id:myData})`

Comment: And anyone who wants to try this out - do not forget to mark your WebService class with [ScriptService] - just had problem with that.

Answer (score 3):

A couple things...

- Your web-service must be marked with a ScriptServiceAttribute to allow it to return JSON (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptserviceattribute.aspx)
- Your $.ajax method must have a "success" handler (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
- The returned JavaScript object will have the same property names as the C# object
- A good way to see the JSON serialized object in transit is to use Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

Some ***untested*** sample code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  url: "WebService.asmx/GetData",
  data: "{id}",
  dataType: "json"
  success: function(data) {
    var str = '' +
      'UserName: ' + data.UserName + '\n' +
      'Password: ' + data.Password + '\n' +
      'FirstName: ' + data.FirstName + '\n' +
      'LastName: ' + data.LastName + '\n' +
      'MiddleName: ' + data.MiddleName;
    alert(str);
  }
});
```