# JSON doesn't work with typed class in Webservice

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services, json, asmx

I'm having a class like the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

[DataContract()]
public class TestCol : List<Test> { }

[DataContract()]
public class MainTest
{
    public TestCol Components { get; set; }
}

[DataContract()]
public class Test
{
    public Test() { }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

And a webservice with the following webmethod like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public String Test(MainTest input)
{
    String rtrn = String.Empty;
    foreach (Test test in input.Components)
        rtrn += test.Name;
    return rtrn;
}
```

Which is called by AJAX with the following method:

```
var Test = {};
Test.Name = "Test";

var MainTest = {};
MainTest.Components = [];
MainTest.Components.push(Test);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "WebService/WSTest.asmx/Test",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        "input": MainTest 
    }),
    success: function(data, textStatus) {
        console.log("success");
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        window.console && console.log && console.log(XMLHttpRequest.responseText + " || " + textStatus + " || " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

When executing the AJAX call, it will return errors. I found out that the error is with the typed class `TestCol`, which has no properties.
Now do I have found 2 solutions that require changes in the C# classes:

1. Remove the `TestCol` class and change the `Components` property to `List<Test>` datatype:

   ```
   [DataContract()]
   public class MainTest
   {
       public List<Test> Components { get; set; }
   }

   [DataContract()]
   public class Test
   {
       public Test() { }
       public String Name { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Or add an extra property to the `TestCol` class and change the webmethod:

   ```
   [DataContract()]
   public class TestCol : List<Test>
   {
       public List<Test> Components { get; set; }
   }

   [DataContract()]
   public class MainTest
   {
       public TestCol Components { get; set; }
   }

   [DataContract()]
   public class Test
   {
       public Test() { }
       public String Name { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   &

   ```
   [WebMethod]
   public String Test(MainTest input)
   {
       String rtrn = String.Empty;
       foreach (Test test in input.Components.Components)
               rtrn += test.Name;
       return rtrn;
   }
   ```

Both solutions require changes in the C# classes, which I prefer not to, as other code is depended on it. **Does anyone know a solution for this problem?**

*Edit*: I've uploaded a test solution, containing above code: http://jeroenvanwarmerdam.nl/content/temp/JSONtoClassWebservice.zip

Comment: Were you aware that `DataContract` relates to WCF, and not to ASMX web services?

Comment: Can you give info on the error you received?  I have used DataContract on empty classes before with no prob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### JavaScriptSerializer serialization: IEnumerable -> JavaScript Array

When the JavaScriptSerializer is used, it automatically converts an IEnumerable (without IDictionary) type -- that covers List<> or anything derived from it -- into an array.

### Deserialization: JavaScript Array -> IEnumerable -> Collection Object

Now, upon **deserialization** from JSON, the JavaScriptSerializer must take the array, create an IEnumerable, then create an object for the field by passing that IEnumerable into its constructor.

### Constructing Collection object via Constructor

Now, for List<> you have a constructor overload that takes an IEnumerable.  So if you put `List<Test>` as the type of your component it creates it fine.

### Constructors not inherited

However, TestCol does **NOT** have such a constructor!  The reason why it worked with `List<Test>` and not with `TestCol` (which derives from `List<Test>`) is that the only thing that is **not** inherited between classes are constructors!

Therefore, the JavaScriptSerializer does not have any way to construct a TestCol from an IEnumerable.  So it fails silently.

### Deserialize Array by Creating List, then Casting to Type

Now the JavaScriptSerializer may then attempt to create a `List<Test>` from this `IEnumerable<Test>`, and then try to cast it into a TestCol.

### Possible Solution

Solution: Try putting in:

```
public TestCol () {}       // Need this when you have another constructor
public TestCol (IEnumerable<Test> list) : base(list) {}         // Constructor that takes an IEnumerable
public TestCol (IList<Test> list) : base(list) {}         // Constructor that takes an IList
```

as your TestCol's constructors.

And if it still doesn't work, implement an explicit type cast from `List<Test>` to `TestCol`.

```
public static explicit operator TestCol(IList<Test> list) { return new TestCol(list); }
```

Answer (score 1):

So this solution changes the List to Object instead of Test. I hoped to change as little code as possible (i dislike having to do casts in foreach loops). The below code does so with two function additions and the previously mentioned inheritance change.

```
public class TestCol : List<object>
{
    public new IEnumerator<Test> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.ConvertAll<Test>(
            dict => ConvertDictionaryTo<Test>(
                       (Dictionary<string, object>) dict
                    )
        ).GetEnumerator();
    }

    private T ConvertDictionaryTo<T>(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary) where T : new()
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        T ret = new T();

        foreach (var keyValue in dictionary)
        {
            type.GetProperty(keyValue.Key).SetValue(ret, keyValue.Value, null);
        }

        return ret;
    }
}
```

Convert function courtesy TurBas
[Mapping object to dictionary and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943817/mapping-object-to-dictionary-and-vice-versa/4944268#4944268)

Comment: I suppose this conversion could also happen in the getter/setter method MainTest.Components

Comment: Thanks Michael Gillette. This is almost what I was looking for. I was hoping to use the `List<Test>` class type, but that seems not to be possible (to my knowledge)... If no better solution present itself, I'll reward the points to you.

Comment: Are you sure the List<> is giving you the problem?  Seems you can serialize a List<> with DataContract.  Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347850.aspx

Comment: In the solution suggested above by Michael, is `List<Test>` instead of `List<Object>` giving me problems.
In my original test, not the list is giving problems, but the custom class `TestCol` which inherit from `List<Test>` is giving me problems. Removing the `TestCol` completely solves my problem, but that's just not what I wanted.
Above solution seems oke, but I wished I could use `List<Test>` instead of `List<Object>`.

Answer (score 0):

hmmm this didn't work in the web method?

```
  foreach (Test test in input.Components.TestCol)
```

Re comment below, does this work then?

```
  foreach (Test test in (List<Test>)input.Components.TestCol)
```

It should work because a class can be enumerated...

Comment: That can't be, because `TestCol` is a class and not a property.

Comment: Appreciate your help, but this also isn't the solution :( I do have uploaded a test solution with above code: http://jeroenvanwarmerdam.nl/content/temp/JSONtoClassWebservice.zip

Answer (score 0):

If you're expecting JSON, you'll need to return JSON.
Check with the System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx

Comment: That's not the problem here. The problem is that I POST JSON to a webservice, which automatic convert these to a custom class. Everything works correctly, except for the `TestCol` class. Returning a `String` was just for testing purpose.

Comment: yikes my bad.  hopefully someone finds my answer useful, haha.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ASMX services the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) will be responsible for the data conversion and not the [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx). So all `DataContract` attributes which you use **will not work**.

You are write that classes like `public class TestCol : List<Test> { }` are bad for the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx), but classes having `List<Test>` as the property (`public class MainTest { public List<Test> Components { get; set; }}`) have no problem.

So I suggest to simplify you code to the following. The classes used as the parameters can be defines as

```
public class Test {
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

public class MainTest {
    public List<Test> Components { get; set; }
}
```

The WebMethod `Test` will be

```
[WebMethod]
public String Test(MainTest input)
{
    StringBuilder rtrn = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (Test test in input.Components) {
        rtrn.AppendLine (test.Name);
    }
    return rtrn.ToString ();
}
```

and the ajax call can be

```
var tests = {
    Components: [
        {Name:"Test1"},
        {Name:"Test2"},
        {Name:"Test3"}
    ]
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "WebService1.asmx/Test",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        "input": tests
    }),
    success: function (data, textStatus) {
        alert("success:\n" + data.d);
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText+" || "+textStatus+" || "+errorThrown);
    }
});
```

How you can see all will be very simple and it's work. For more details how you can send complex data I recommend you to read [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445859/asmx-web-service-json-javascript-jquery/3446517#3446517) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737525/how-do-i-build-a-json-object-to-send-to-an-ajax-webservice/2738086#2738086).

Comment: @jerone: Do you could reproduce the changes which I suggested? If it will help I could upload the modified code of your project and post the url to you.

Comment: This is precisely the same suggestion as I mentioned in the first solution. Problem is that the project heavily uses the `TestCol` class for defining the `new List<Test>();`, which I can't replace.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using ASMX (not WCF) because you have omitted `[DataMember]` attributes on all your public properties and still get serialized.  WCF is "opt-in", so you shouldn't be seeing any serialization of any properly.

As a result, all `[DataContract]` attributes are useless.

ASMX defaults to the JavaScriptSerializer if you are using ScriptManger and outputing JSON. The JavaScriptSerializer is "opt-out" (which means that all public properties are automatically serialized unless marked with `[ScriptIgnoreAttribute]`).

The JavaScriptSerializer supports serializing List<>'s.  You should not be having problems serializing your TestCol property because JavaScriptSerializer automatically supports serializing all types that implement IEnumerable (but not IDictionary) -- which includes List<> -- into JSON arrays.

Your error seems to be that the JavaScriptSerializer does not properly handle classes that *inherit* from List<> (or from a class implementing IEnumerable).  In your first work-around, you eliminated the class that inherited from List<>.  In your second work-around, you skipped all functionalities of the base class, but re-implemented the List<> in a property.

Your JSON post data currently looks like:

```
{ Components: [
    { Name:"foo" },
    { Name:"bar" },
        :
] }
```

However, you have one extra level or redirection in the serializer (inheriting from `List<Test>` -> `TestCol`).  It is possible that the serializer is looking for:

```
{ Components: {
    Items: [
        { Name:"foo" },
        { Name:"bar" },
            :
    ] }
}
```

because you are essentially serializing the "Items" property of List<>.  So, your JSON post data is just feeding Test objects to the wrong place, and your TestCol Components property ends up empty.

I'd suggest that you add a web service method to output a test MainTest object to see what it serializes into.  You'll probably find that it puts in an additional level.

Comment: Thanks for taking time. Taking your suggestion to action and created a `MainTest` with 2 `Test` in its `Components`. The result is the following as expected: `({__type:"JSONtoClassWebservice.MainTest", Components:[{Name:"Test 1"}, {Name:"Test 2"}]})`. Anyway we can fool the JavaScriptSerializer?

Comment: This is serializing the one with TestCol, right?  In this case, just post this exact JSON (together with the __type property) back to your web service and see what happens...