# POST JSON data to .asmx webservice

Tags: jquery, json, rest, asmx

I'm trying to post some simple parameters to a .asmx webservice.
I get the following error: ***Request format is invalid: application/json; charset=utf-8.***
What I really need to get to is to be able to pass a complex object, but I can't get past making a POST request with json content type.

Here is my WebService Definition

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public int JsonTest2(int myparm1, int myparm2)
{
    return 101;
}
```

And this is my javascript code

```
function JsonTest2() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "http://localhost/WebServices/MyTest.asmx/JsonTest2",
        data: "{myparm1:105,myparm2:23}",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            alert('failure');
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: which asp.net version are you using? shouldn't there be a msg.d in the success callback?

Answer (score 5):

Make sure your ASMX service class is decorated with the `[ScriptService]` attribute.

Comment: It would be good if you mention the minimum .Net version needed for this.

Answer (score 2):

You should use as `data` the value which formatted as correct JSON data:

```
{"myparm1":105,"myparm2":23}
```

instead of

```
{myparm1:105,myparm2:23}
```

You can validate on the site http://www.jsonlint.com/ which data are JSON data. So you should change your code to

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://localhost/WebServices/MyTest.asmx/JsonTest2",
    data: '{"myparm1":105,"myparm2":23}',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function (msg) {
        alert(msg.d);
    },
    error: function (msg) {
        alert('failure');
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```

In case of more complex input parameters I recommend you to use `JSON.stringify` functionfrom the [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445859/asmx-web-service-json-javascript-jquery/3446517#3446517) for example):

```
var myValue1 = 105, myValue2 = 23;
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({myparm1:myValue1, myparm2:myValue2}),
    ...
});
```

In the last version of `$.ajax` usage the `myValue1` and `myValue2` can be complex structures (objects with properties) or arrays having even another complex structures or arrays as the properties.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the URL contains port number when using localhost.

```
  url: "http://localhost:1297/WebServices/MyTest.asmx/JsonTest2",
```