# Extracting data values - jQuery

Tags: jquery, web-services

am calling a webservice from my jquery as

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/DataService.asmx/Search",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: "{'date' : '" + $("#txtDate").val() + "'}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {

        },
        error: function (req, status, error) {
        }
    });
```

in the data am receiving some values like `"[{"Id":10,"Name":"abdul  samathu","Mobile":"8147708287","Email":"shanish.mca@gmail.com"}]"`

here how can I get the values alone, I tried like

```
var name=data.Name;
var mobile=data.Mobile like this, but its not working can anyone help me here
```

Comment: chck this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445859/asmx-web-service-json-javascript-jquery/3446517#3446517

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

`data[0].Name` and `data[0].Mobile`

Comment: thanks for ur response, it says error like Name is null or undefined, I tried the code var name=data[0].Name;

Comment: you can check what is coming in data variable using console.log(data); Make sure data should be an object, not a  string also should have Name parameter. Response format must be same otherwise we have to place conditions to get data accordingly.

Comment: if I use data=jQuery.parseJSON(data.d) its working fine, I can see the seperated arrays, but the problem is when I put the breakpoint here It shows the values at 0th index,within that 0th index again....then only the valus are displayed, how can I get the Name of Oth of 0th of data......

Answer (score 2):

What I am doing here is calling the web service, and looping the json objects and printing the items name. You can change it according to your needs, but this works.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/DataService.asmx/Search",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    data: "{'date' : '" + $("#txtDate").val() + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {

        if (data.d != null)
            data = data.d;

for (var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++) {
    console.log(data[i].Name);
}

    },
    error: function (x, y, z) { } // 
});
```

Comment: Instead of    console.log(data[i].Name), put alert(data[i].Name).

Comment: if I use data=jQuery.parseJSON(data.d) its working fine, I can see the seperated arrays, but the problem is when I put the breakpoint here It shows the values at 0th index,within that 0th index again....then only the valus are displayed, how can I get the Name of Oth of 0th of data......

Comment: If you use firebug, and view the console, you can drill down the objects and see what they contain. Console.log(data), so you can see the raw object.

Answer (score 1):

Your `data` is an array of objects, not a single object. Use `data[0].Name` to access the first object's name.

Edit: based on your post, for some reason `data` looks like a string, not proper JSON-decoded array. Try the following:

```
data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
console.log(data);
var name = data[0].Name;
console.log(name);
```

Comment: hi DCoder thanks for ur response, I tried ur code,it says error like Name is null or undefined

Comment: after executing this line data = jQuery.parseJSON(data); the value of data becomes null, whats the problem

Comment: if I use data=jQuery.parseJSON(data.d) its working fine, I can see the seperated arrays, but the problem is when I put the breakpoint here It shows the values at 0th index,within that 0th index again....then only the valus are displayed, how can I get the Name of Oth of 0th of data......

Answer (score 1):

instead of $.ajax use $.getJSON() 
for usage please gone through following link
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/