# passing multiple parameters to .asmx from jquery ajax GET

Tags: c#, jquery

html

```
<a onclick="testGetParametersDynamic2();">fill in names and check it out</a>
<br />
<p>Enter First Name</p>
<input id="myFirstName" type="text" />
<br />
<p>Enter Last Name</p>
<input id="myLastName" type="text" />
<div id="outputGET3"></div>
```

c#

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public string testGetParametersDynamic(string firstName, string lastName)
{
    string fullName = firstName + lastName;

    return fullName;
}
```

I have tried multiple ways of entering data bc I think this is where the problem lies

attempt 1

```
function testGetParametersDynamic2()
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            post: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: '{"firstName":"' + $('#myFirstName').val() + '","lastName":' +
                    $('#myLastName').val() + '"}',
            url: 'UtilitieService.asmx/TestGetParametersDynamic',
            success: function (result)
            {
                var test = result.d;
                var outputDiv = $('outputGET3');
                outputDiv.html(test);
            },

            error: function ()
            {
                alert('Fail Test Get Dynamic');
            }
        });
    }
```

attempt 2:

```
function testGetParametersDynamic2()
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            post: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: "firstName" + $('myFirstName').val() + "&lastName" + $('myLastName').val(),
            url: 'UtilitieService.asmx/TestGetParametersDynamic',
            success: function (result)
            {
                var test = result.d;
                var outputDiv = $('outputGET3');
                outputDiv.html(test);
            },

            error: function ()
            {
                alert('Fail Test Get Dynamic');
            }
        });
    }
```

both times I get this error:

Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027firstName\u0027

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I hope that you use `[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)]` attribute for the web method or set the same information in the web.config in case of the usage .NET 4.0.

It seems to me that your first attempt was almost correct, but you should replace

```
data: '{"firstName":"' + $('#myFirstName').val() + '","lastName":' +
                    $('#myLastName').val() + '"}',
```

to the

```
data: '{"firstName":"' + $('#myFirstName').val() + '","lastName":"' +
                    $('#myLastName').val() + '"}',
```

(the starting double-quote was skipped before the `$('#myLastName').val()`).

I strictly recommend you don't use manual serialization to JSON. For example if the text from `$('#myFirstName').val()` or `$('#myLastName').val()` will have '"' or '\' characters, that the characters must be escaped with additional backslash ('\') (see [here](http://www.json.org/)). Instead of manual serialization you should use `JSON.stringify` function from the script json2.js which you can download from the http://www.json.org/js.html or [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js). In recent web browsers the function are native implemented and json2.js use the native implementation if it take place.

The `data` parameter of `$.ajax` could be rewritten as the following:

```
data: {
    firstName: JSON.stringify($('myFirstName').val()),
    lastName: JSON.stringify($('myLastName').val())
}
```

or in some situation even as

```
data: {
    firstName: function() { return JSON.stringify($('myFirstName').val()); },
    lastName: function() { return JSON.stringify($('myLastName').val()); }
}
```

For more information see [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737525/how-do-i-build-a-json-object-to-send-to-an-ajax-webservice/2738086#2738086) and probably also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651091/jquery-ajax-call-to-httpget-webmethod-c-not-working/2656543#2656543).

**UPDATED**: Sorry the correct version without the usage `JSON.stringify` could be without the data usage:

```
url: 'UtilitieService.asmx/TestGetParametersDynamic?firstName=' +
     encodeURIComponent('"' + $('#myFirstName').val() + '"') +
     '&lastName=' + encodeURIComponent('"' + $('#myLastName').val() + '"')
```

I strictly recommend you to use always only the `JSON.stringify` version which I described above.

Comment: updated the code using your code with addition double-quote. Still getting same error. This is the statement from firebug ?{"firstName":"dan","lastName":"mark"}. Is that right format?

Comment: @dan_vitch: Why you don't use the version with `JSON.stringify`? You will has correct results in the case.

Answer (score 2):

- Your first attempt is passing the paramaters as a json string.
- Your second attempt is missing `=` signs.

You can pass a object to `data`, and jQuery will serialize it properly.

```
$.ajax(
        {
            post: 'GET',
            data: {
                firstName: $('myFirstName').val(),
                lastName: $('myLastName').val()
            },
...
```

Comment: Note: Avoid making the call as `GET`. Use `POST` instead. See http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/04/json-hijacking-and-how-asp-net-ajax-1-0-mitigates-these-attacks.aspx

Comment: Also, `post: 'GET'` - i think you are looking for the `type` option instead of the `post`(?) option.

Comment: @Scrum I updated code and received this error: Invalid JSON primitive: dan. dan was the name I used in firstName field.

Answer (score 0):

Pass multiple parameters using json

```
data: "{'RecomendeeName':'" + document.getElementById('txtSearch').value + 
                       "'," + "'tempdata':'" +"myvalue" + "'}",
```