# ASP webservice using GET parameters and return JSON object

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services, getmethod

Im having a problem with my web service.  When I pass the parameters as POST and in a JSON format, It returns a JSON object. I want to convert the POST to a GET but the problem is, the web service only returns in XML format.

```
<script>   
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/web_services/webservice.asmx/getReturnJson",
        data: "params1=1",
        contentType: "application/*; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json")
</script>
```

The web service:

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public List<tempStruct> getReturnJson(String params1)
    { 
     return temp;
    }
```

Comment: For now, Ill have to use the POST method for my parameters.

Answer (score 0):

if you are having problems with GET parameters not being properly parse set them in the URL.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/web_services/webservice.asmx/getReturnJson?params=1",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8")
```

Also make sure you have all the configs appropriate.

```
<httpHandlers>
    <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
    <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory"     validate="false"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

Comment: Currently it returns in XML format. I invoked the json format so that it would return a JSON object. what i noticed is that if i place contentType:"application/json" it would return a json object but it has problems with get parameters. when contentType is default, it takes in the get parameters but returns in an xml format

Comment: this might be able to help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651091/jquery-ajax-call-to-httpget-webmethod-c-not-working

Comment: i also tried to include the parameters in the url.. it returns an error stating there is no web service for said url. it includes the parameters as the web service url name.

Comment: that would actually work but the main reason why i wanted it to be a GET method because i want my parameters to be in the usual url.com?param1=1&param2=2

Comment: if `http://localhost/web_services/webservice.asmx/getReturnJson?params=1` didn't work than you may need to look at your web config, also please make sure `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]` is at the the top of your class definition.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that it doesn't accept POST request for security reasons