# WebForms GET Json requests (JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have an old WebForms project that needs revisiting and I want to add some new features.

I want to load the data using $.getJSON(), this is very simple in ASP.NET MVC because you can return the data like this,

```
return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

The Get doesn't work in WebForms,

```
// Http GET request
$.getJSON('Attributes.aspx/GetAttributes', { 'ProductId': '3' }, function (d) { alert(d); });
```

The Post works.

```
// Http POST 
$.post('Attributes.aspx/GetAttributes', { 'ProductId': '3' }, function (d) { alert(d); });
```

Here is the WebForms WebMethod,

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetAttributes(string ProductId)
{
    List<QuoteAttribute> list = DAL.GetAttributes(ProductId);
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
    return json;
}
```

I want to return json using the GET method.

Is there an `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` for WebForms?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Another [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651091/jquery-ajax-call-to-httpget-webmethod-c-not-working) that shows how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Need to add "[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]" before the method.This will allow GET method.
eg.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public static string GetAttributes(string ProductId)
{
    List<QuoteAttribute> list = DAL.GetAttributes(ProductId);
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
    return json;
}
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation to your question?