# trying to send value from front end javascript to backend c# using ajax call,but the value is getting NULL in backend,i don't know where i did mistake

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asmx

### Expecting

What will be the value in the textbox that value should be sent to the backend? I think the issue with the call, but I don't where it is

### Javascript

```
function employeeLeavesList() {
                        var emp = {}
                        emp.EMPID = $("#employid").val();
                        alert(emp.EMPID);
                        $.ajax({
                            type:'POST',
                            url: 'service.asmx/employee_leaveslist',
                            data: JSON.stringify(emp),
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (data) {}
                        });

                    }
```

### class.cs

```
public class emp
{
    public string EMPID { get; set; }
}
```

### webmethod.asmx.cs

```
[WebMethod]
        public void employee_leaveslist()
        {
            emp emp = new emp();
            List<employee_leave_list> list = new List<employee_leave_list>();
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source = Champ; Initial Catalog = sample; Integrated Security = True");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select emp_id,leaves_form, leaves_upto, leave_type, description, status, no_of_leaves from leaverequest where emp_id = '" + emp.EMPID + "' ", connection);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader idr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            connection.Close();

        }
```

Comment: It's normal,because you instantiate ``emp`` inside method.try to send it like a parameter:``employee_leaveslist(emp emp){····}

Comment: In asmx parameters not allowed

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651091/jquery-ajax-call-to-httpget-webmethod-c-not-working/2656543#2656543, you can pass the value in your url, instead of using Post method.

Answer (score 0):

First, modify the 'data' parameter of your $.ajax() call as below,

```
data: { empid : $('#employid').val() },
```

Then, modify the first line of webmethod employee_leaveslist(),

```
emp emp = new emp(){ EMPID  = (string)Request.Form["empid"] };
```