# In ASP.NET Web Forms, how to call a page method using "get" request

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

In ASP.NET Web Forms, i am able to call page method using Ajax "post" request. But i am not able to call the page method using "get request".

In this case, is it possible to call page methods using "Get" request.?Could you please provide any suggestion for this?
Example Code for Page method:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetData()
    {            
        return "test";
    }
```

Comment: What happens when you try to call the method? any error exceptions?

Comment: did you try to decorate your method with [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true)]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As @vc mentioned in the comments you'll need to make use of the `ScriptMethodAttribute` as well as `WebMethod` because you want your request to be `GET` and not `POST` so change your code as follows:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public static string GetData()
{
   return "test";
}
```

And in the markup you can do

```
function ShowTestMessage() {
     $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "YourPage.aspx/GetData",
          data: {},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: OnSuccess,
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
});
}
function OnSuccess(response) {
alert(response.d);
}

<input id="ButtonId" type="button" value="Show Message"
onclick = "ShowTestMessage()" />
```

Don't forget to add the following reference

```
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Services;
```

Comment: Yes it's working. Tested with a old version of JQuery. Sorry bout that !

Comment: @Izzy, is it necessary to send the data as **JSON** in order to make a successful call? I mean, what would happen if you remove `contentType` from the settings?

Answer (score 4):

[Ajax GET requests to an ASP.NET Page Method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397466/ajax-get-requests-to-an-asp-net-page-method)

I guess the link would be useful. It says **For security reasons, ASP.Net AJAX page methods only support POST requests.**

Tried decorating the method with [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
but still the get request is not hit.

Also the msdn doc for [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)] 
quotes  **When this property is set to true, the client proxy code uses HTTP GET to call the Web service.** Not sure if it works for a webmethod in web forms.

**P.S** : Well seems to work with the newer versions of Jquery 2.2.2. Also please be sure that you send data through query strings not using request body as in POST method.