# ASP.NET webmethod get ajax with parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I have a webmethod like this:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public static string test(string Name, int? Age)
{
    return "returned value";
}
```

And the ajax call :

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "form.aspx/test",
  data: {'Name': "n1", 'Age': 30},
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Without parameters/data it works, but when I try to pass some parameters I get this error:

```
GET http://localhost:55410/test.aspx/test?Name=n1&Age=30
500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I think this's the detailed exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: Unknown web method form.
Parameter name: methodName
```

Comment: the error message listed that the url of the method is 'test2' not 'test' is this a typo or something else?

Comment: @AmrElgarhy sorry, it's a typo.

Comment: @AmrElgarhy Please check my last update to the question, I added the detailed exception.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET jQuery error: Unknown Web Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179934/asp-net-jquery-error-unknown-web-method)

Comment: @AmrElgarhy My web method is `public` and `static`

Comment: Again the error saying ‘test.aspx’ while your Ajax call ‘form.aspx’ !

Comment: @AmrElgarhy very sorry, edited that.

Comment: So the page name called form.aspx and the method is test, right?

Comment: @AmrElgarhy yes

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass an object instead of a string, and put quotes around `n1` to make it a string:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "test.aspx/test",
  data: {'Name': 'n1', 'Age': 30},  // remove quotes & add quotes to n1
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: still the same error. `GET http://localhost:55410/test.aspx/test2?Name=n1&Age=30`   `500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: @Den whoops sorry since `n1` is a `string` you need to put quotes around it. Fixed my answer

Comment: @Den where is the `test2` in the url coming from?

Comment: sorry, it's a typo.

Comment: @Den ok gotcha, so `http://localhost:55410/test.aspx/test` works right?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "works", but as I mentioned on the question when I use it without the parameters it works. Does it mean that this `http://localhost:55410/test.aspx/test` works?

Comment: @Den what I meant is that when you type `http://localhost:55410/test.aspx/test` into your browser, do you get back `"returned value"` rendered on your browser. Just sanity check.

Comment: Please check my last update to the question, I added the detailed exception.

Comment: @Den just something to try, can you remove the line `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` and try, if that fails, try cleaning the browser cache with ctrl+f5 to see if it's caching the `GET`, clean the project, rebuild it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass parameters with url you dont need to use `data` property at all: 
Just pass them in the url itself like below:

```
 $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "form.aspx/test?name=" + yourStringVariabel + "&age=" + yourAgeVariabel,
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Try with a post and see if it works:

```
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "form.aspx/test",
  data: JSON.stringify({ name: 'N1', age : 1 }),
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: same error `GET http://localhost:55410/form.aspx/test?Name=n1&Age=1`    `500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: Why is your method static @Den ?

Comment: @Den can you please set the type to 'POST' instead of 'GET' and let me know if it works. Now you can use data property like this `data: JSON.stringify({
                           name: 'N1', age : 1
                        }),`

Comment: @Den make the method static again because in the documentation indicates it needs to be static

Comment: @Den refer to this: seems to be a missing feature with the GET for security reasons: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651091/jquery-ajax-call-to-httpget-webmethod-c-not-working and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397466/ajax-get-requests-to-an-asp-net-page-method/2397521#2397521

Comment: But as I mentioned on the question when I use `GET` without the `parameters` it works. Please check my last update to the question, I added the detailed exception.