# When I call a function in asp.net webforms from asp.net core MVC using Ajax is not hitting the target?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I have two project such as Main Project in Dot net Core MVC and Target project in ASP.NET framework webforms I have a Test Method in Webform in Target Project , But I want access the method from Main project using jQuery Ajax But this Code Does not hit the target Method..

From Main Project

```
    $('#btnTest').click(function () {
        AjaxCall();
    });
    function AjaxCall() {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            url: 'https://localhost:44332/WebForm1.aspx/TestMethod',
            success: function (jsondata) {
                alert('Success');
            },
            error: function (request, error) {
                alert("Failed");
            }
        })
    }
</script>

//Target Project Code behind

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Services;
namespace TargetProject
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        [WebMethod]
        public static string TestMethod()
        {
            return "Success";
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can only post to a WebMethod. See this stack overflow [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397466/ajax-get-requests-to-an-asp-net-page-method/2397521#2397521)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET AJAX page methods only support POST requests for security reasons. If you change the method to `POST`, you can't use `JSONP` as dataType.

Change your code in `ASP.NET Core` below:

```
<script>
    $('#btnTest').click(function () {
         AjaxCall();
    });
    function AjaxCall() {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',          //change here.....
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: 'json',      //change here.....
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",       //add this...
            url: 'https://localhost:44332/WebForm1.aspx/TestMethod',
            success: function (jsondata) {
                alert('Success');
            },
            error: function (request, error) {
                alert("Failed");
            }
        })
    }     
</script>
```

Be sure you have configured cors in `web.config` file in `WebForms`:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>  
    <httpProtocol>  
      <customHeaders>  
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="accept, content-type" />  
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />  
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, GET, OPTIONS" />  
      </customHeaders>  
    </httpProtocol>  
  </system.webServer>  
  //.....
</configuration>
```

Be sure change your `RouteConfig.cs` in `App_Start` folder in `WebForms`:

```
public static class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
        //settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
        settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;

        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
    }
}
```

Comment: where I need to Add settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off; because in dot net core does not have RouteConfig.cs

Comment: Hi  @NOUFALKP, RouteConfig.cs is in `App_Start` folders in WebForms project.

Comment: Webforms Project Does not have Any `App_Start` folder, I have Added an Image of Solution Explorer in the Question ,Could you please check that..

Comment: Hi @NOUFALKP, I think you may create a ASP.NET empty template instead of WebForms, you need learn how to create a WebForms template. Refer to:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/create-the-project.

Comment: Again I have Updated my Project as per your Code, Please check the updated images on the Questions ,But A gain it is Not hitting the target

Comment: It is to change RouteConfig.cs code to: `settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off`, pls remove `settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent`.

Comment: Hi @Rena  - I think it is Due to Connection Refused Issue , See the Last Image I have Added, Actually I am using `DevextreamWebApplication`  as the Main Project ,So that I have seen this Error , While I changed the `Normal DotnetCore Web Application` it not getting this Error and it is Working Fine but I have using `Devextream` as My Working Solution , so I have this Connection Refused Error and that is why it is not hitting the Target.

Comment: This error is caused by `settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent` or you write the wrong request url.

Comment: I have Already commented the line `settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent`  and Added `settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off` but it is still show the Error

Comment: Now it is Working, I think that the my Port Number has Changed, Now it is Working.. Thank you soo much for your valuable effort and Time @Rena